# Java GUI JScrollPane hiding text

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, null-layout-manager

Currently I am trying to get a `JScrollPane` to work with a GUI I am creating. I currently have a textarea called `consoleTextArea` and I want to be able to scroll through it. Currently my code is:

```
consoleTextArea = new JTextArea();
consoleTextArea.setBounds(10, 11, 546, 459);

JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(consoleTextArea);
scroller.setBounds(0, 451, 551, -451);
scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
panel.add(scroller);
```

If I use `panel.add(scroller)`, I don't even see the textArea.
If I use `panel.add(consoleTextArea)`, I see the text area but it cannot scroll.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you set the height of a component to a negative value you should not ask why you don’t see anything. Only aliens from the anti-universe will see your component then.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, you're not using a layout manager. Without using a layout manager ([absolute positioning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)) you encounter you encounter these types of problems where components are not sized or positioned correctly. A good reason, therefore to use one.

Read: [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)